# Why Google ping (DNS server 8.8.8.8) in windows is faster than ubuntu 16.04 and Other Linux distribution?

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, lan, ping

I've read all the solutions regarding to similar problems existing in all the community and I've performed these options but none of theme work!
I've checked the google ping both in linux and windows however as you can see in the picture nearly 200ms in needed in order to get packets, but in windows 7 this time is 40ms!

Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter

Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

[Ping google DNS server 8.8.8.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33DeH.png)

Comment: I have noticed the same some time ago. Also the download speed was much lower in Ubuntu 14.04 than in Win 7. But lately things have improved. At least the download speed is more or less the same for both OS. I suppose the driver was updated or something. I have tried to ping google now and I get 45 ms.

Comment: Mine averages 50ms, must be a driver issue, it would help a lot if you added the make and model of your WIFI / LAN

Comment: This appears to vary for everyone. I do't know how, but I get 50% faster internet in Linux.

Comment: I just tried your command and get from `33.1 ms` to `35.1 ms`.

Comment: `10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 5013ms`  :)